# How do I change my IP address using Ruby/Tor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ip-address, tor

I”m using Rails 4.2.7 and I have several Tor gems installed.

```
gem 'tor'
gem 'tor_requests'
gem 'tor-privoxy'
gem 'net-telnet'
```

I started my Tor browser (running on Mac El Capitan) and I want to periodically (every 20th request) change the IP address of where my TOR web requests originate.  So I tried this

```
agent = TorPrivoxy::Agent.new '127.0.0.1', '', {8118 => 9151} do |agent|
  sleep 1
  puts "New IP is #{agent.ip}"
end
```

However, this results in the below error.  I’m confused about how else I need to configure things so that I can make the above work.

```
Error during processing: Failed to open TCP connection to 127.0.0.1:8118 (general SOCKS server failure)
/Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:882:in `rescue in block in connect'
/Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:879:in `block in connect'
/Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/timeout.rb:91:in `block in timeout'
/Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/timeout.rb:101:in `timeout'
/Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:878:in `connect'
/Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
/Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:858:in `start'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/net-http-persistent-2.9.4/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:700:in `start'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/net-http-persistent-2.9.4/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:631:in `connection_for'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/net-http-persistent-2.9.4/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:994:in `request'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/mechanize-2.7.5/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:274:in `fetch'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/mechanize-2.7.5/lib/mechanize.rb:464:in `get'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/tor-privoxy-0.1.1/lib/tor-privoxy/agent.rb:38:in `ip'
/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/helpers/webpage_helper.rb:57:in `block in get_content'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/tor-privoxy-0.1.1/lib/tor-privoxy/agent.rb:11:in `initialize'
/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/helpers/webpage_helper.rb:55:in `new'
/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/helpers/webpage_helper.rb:55:in `rescue in get_content'
/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/helpers/webpage_helper.rb:50:in `get_content'
/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/helpers/webpage_helper.rb:14:in `get_url'
/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/services/onlinerr_race_finder_service.rb:41:in `get_race_list'
/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/services/abstract_race_finder_service.rb:26:in `process_data'
/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/services/run_crawlers_service.rb:18:in `block in run_all_crawlers'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:46:in `each'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:46:in `each'
/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/services/run_crawlers_service.rb:5:in `run_all_crawlers'
(irb):2:in `irb_binding'
/Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/workspace.rb:87:in `eval'
/Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/workspace.rb:87:in `evaluate'
/Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/context.rb:380:in `evaluate'
/Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb.rb:489:in `block (2 levels) in eval_input'
/Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb.rb:623:in `signal_status'
/Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb.rb:486:in `block in eval_input'
/Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:246:in `block (2 levels) in each_top_level_statement'
/Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:232:in `loop'
/Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:232:in `block in each_top_level_statement'
/Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:231:in `catch'
/Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:231:in `each_top_level_statement'
/Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb.rb:485:in `eval_input'
/Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb.rb:395:in `block in start'
/Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb.rb:394:in `catch'
/Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb.rb:394:in `start'
```

How do I programmatically force an IP address change using Ruby/Tor?

**Edit:**Here is what I included in my helper file and below is the error that results

```
require 'rubygems'
$:.unshift "./tor/lib"
require 'tor'
…
    cookie_file = '/Users/davea/Library/Application Support/TorBrowser-Data/Tor/control_auth_cookie'
    file = File.open(cookie_file, 'rb')
    cookie = file.read # read contents of auth cookie to string
    file.close

    Tor::Controller.connect(:port => 9150, :cookie => cookie) do |tor|
      tor.signal('NEWNYM') # send NEWNYM signal (gets new IP)
    end
```

The error that results in the rails console …

```
Error during processing: undefined method `signal' for #<Tor::Controller:0x007fe044b1e550>
/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/helpers/webpage_helper.rb:87:in `block in get_content'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/tor-0.1.2/lib/tor/control.rb:38:in `connect'
/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/helpers/webpage_helper.rb:86:in `rescue in get_content'
```

**Edit 2:**

After adding this to my Gemfile file

```
gem 'tor', :git => 'https://github.com/dryruby/tor.rb.git'
```

I ran the code above, and now got the error …

```
Error during processing: end of file reached
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bundler/gems/tor.rb-08e589d17196/lib/tor/control.rb:301:in `readline'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bundler/gems/tor.rb-08e589d17196/lib/tor/control.rb:301:in `read_reply'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bundler/gems/tor.rb-08e589d17196/lib/tor/control.rb:194:in `authenticate'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bundler/gems/tor.rb-08e589d17196/lib/tor/control.rb:282:in `send_command'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bundler/gems/tor.rb-08e589d17196/lib/tor/control.rb:269:in `signal'
/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/helpers/webpage_helper.rb:90:in `block in get_content'
```

Answer (score 3):

To change your IP in Tor, you need to connect directly to the controller (it uses a telnet-like line based command/response [protocol](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/control-spec.txt).

It looks like you're trying to connect through Privoxy which isn't necessary.  The controller only allows local connections by default.

Tor Browser's Tor config enforces authentication uses the cookie method, without changing any options in `torrc` you need to read the contents of the auth cookie to connect.

I was able to change the IP with the following code:

```
require 'rubygems'
$:.unshift "./tor/lib"
require 'tor'

# the cookie file contains a "password" for authentication, 32 random bytes
cookie_file = '/home/me/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/control_auth_cookie'
file = File.open(cookie_file, 'rb')
cookie = file.read # read contents of auth cookie to string
file.close

Tor::Controller.connect(:port => 9151, :cookie => cookie) do |tor|
    p tor.signal('NEWNYM') # send NEWNYM signal (gets new IP)
end
```

`tor.signal` returns a string, which should read "250 OK" if the NEWNYM command was successful.  There is some internal rate limiting which prevents this from being run too often (like every 10 seconds I think) which shouldn't be a problem for you.

EDIT:  The 0.1.2 (current release) of this Gem doesn't include the `signal` method from the master branch.  You'll need to use the latest code or replicate [their code](https://github.com/dryruby/tor.rb/blob/master/lib/tor/control.rb#L262) instead of calling signal.

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm using Mac El Capitan, so what do I need to put for "cookie_file ="?  I have no "control_auth_cookie" file anywhere on my machine.

Comment: It should be within the Tor data directory that Tor Browser creates along with all the other network data and state files.

Comment: Cool, I found it.  I updated my answer to list the error I based on running your code (the error was "Error during processing: undefined method `signal' for #<Tor::Controller:0x007fe0449bc338>")

Comment: Added comment about signal not being available in the latest release, only in master.

Comment: Gotcha.  Ok this time I got the master and the error I encountered was "Error during processing: end of file reached".  I put a more complete stack trace in the second edit to my question.

Comment: Not really sure what that means or why it gets that.  Any reason you're wanting to use Tor Browser instead of an actual Tor daemon you have more control over?

Comment: If that sovles my problem, then I'm all in, I just can't figure out if that option is available for Mac.  When I Google "Mac tor daemon," I don't acutally get anything taht says its a daemon.

Comment: See https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-doc-osx.html.en - I hope it solves the problem, but not sure it will completely.  At least it'll be installed in a customary location, won't rely on the browser running, and be more configurable and use the defaults (ports 9050 and 9051).  You'll need to edit torrc to enable the control port as this is off by default.